# Jquery show div when reaching 50% height of another div

Tags: html, jquery

I am using this code to hide `.wp-filter` when reaching the end of `.wpgb-layout`

```
   jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= jQuery('.wpgb-layout').offset().top + jQuery('.wpgb-layout').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
       jQuery('.wp-filter').fadeOut();
  }
});
```

However, I need to modify this code so that `.wp-filter` is also fade-in when the user has scrolled at least 50% height of `.wpgb-layout`

Answer (score 0):

Just add another if clause checking if your `scrollTop()` value is above `0.5` of your `.wpgb-layout`

```
jQuery(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  let wpbgHeight = jQuery('.wpgb-layout').outerHeight();
  let wpbgTopOffset = jQuery('.wpgb-layout').offset().top;
  let innerHeight = window.innerHeight;
  if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() >= wpbgHeight + wpbgTopOffset - window.innerHeight) {
       jQuery('.wp-filter').fadeOut();
  }
  if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() <= 0.5*wpbgHeight + wpbgTopOffset - window.innerHeight) {
       jQuery('.wp-filter').fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi this works when the user scrolls down. However, when the user scrolls back up this doesn't work correctly...

Comment: Also it seems that the filter appears sooner than 50% of the height of wpgb-layout